# prepared statement missing bind variable within a LIKE clause

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have a prepared statement defined as:

```
selectLikeShortnameStmt = cassandraDatasource.getSession().prepare(" select  id,
     parent_id, ultimate_parent_id, internal_ref, short_name,
     long_name, controlling_team from counterparty where short_name like'%?%'");
```

but when I try to use this in the DAO like:

```
PreparedStatement pStmt = statementFactory.getSelectLikeShortnameStmt();
BoundStatement bStmt = pStmt.bind( short_name );
```

I get an error saying the Prepared statement has no bind variables.
To implement the like clause I am using the SASI index functionality ie:

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX short_name_like_index ON counterparty (short_name)
USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex'
WITH OPTIONS = { 'mode': 'CONTAINS' };
```

Comment: add a space after like and start with :?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above post worked fine for straightforward PreparedStatement with bind variable but I had another similar issue. I am using the Apache Lucerne index builder for more complex queries ie. ranges with an index definition like:

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX counterparty_column_index ON counterparty (filter_column)
USING 'com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.Index'
WITH OPTIONS = {
    'schema' : '{
        fields : {
        controlling_team     : {type : "text", analyzer : "english"},
        relationship_manager : {type : "text", analyzer : "english"},
        review_date          : {type : "date", pattern : "dd-MM-yyyy"}
        }
    }'
};
```

and the statement defined as :

```
    log.info("CounterpartyStatement [selectByReviewDateAndTeamStmt]");
    selectByReviewDateAndTeamStmt       =  cassandraDatasource.getSession().prepare(" select  id, parent_id, ultimate_parent_id, internal_ref, short_name, long_name, controlling_team, " +
                                            " country_incorp, country_operate, company_reg, relationship_manager, credit_rating, rating_source, pd, lgd, review_date, sector, defaulted, own_bank_entity " +
                                            " from counterparty where filter_column = '{ " 
                                                         + " filter : {type:\"range\", field:\"review_date\", lower:\"01-01-2000\", upper:\"%s\"},"
                                                         + " query : {type:\"contains\", field:\"controlling_team\", values:[\"%s\"]},"
                                                         + " refresh:true"
                                                         + " }'");
```

This formatting was necessary because the standard PreparedStatement bind was not picking up the usual ? placeholders.

The code then became:

```
log.info("CounterpartyDAO.getRmCounterpartiesForReview [" + rm + "]");
    PreparedStatement pStmt = statementFactory.getSelectByReviewDateAndRmStmt();

    String query = pStmt.getQueryString();
    Date maxDate = dateUtils.addDays( dateUtils.getToday(), 3);
    String maxDateString = dateUtils.getAnyDate(maxDate, "dd-MM-yyyy");
    query = String.format( query, maxDateString, rm );

    ResultSet rs = cassandraDatasource.getSession().execute( query );
```

which also worked fine, the dateUtils is just a package I wrote for manipulating dates etc.

Answer (score 1):

The doesn't work because `?` used in `'%?%'` is part of a string, it's not its own bind variable, instead you would need to do the following:

```
selectLikeShortnameStmt = cassandraDatasource.getSession().prepare("select id, parent_id, ultimate_parent_id, internal_ref, short_name, long_name, controlling_team from counterparty where short_name like ?");
PreparedStatement pStmt = statementFactory.getSelectLikeShortnameStmt();
BoundStatement bStmt = pStmt.bind("%" + short_name + "%");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is coming from your binding. As in the examples here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

You probably want to do something like: `pStmt.setString(short_name);`

Comment: Hi, i tried :    from counterparty where short_name like '%:?%'") and got same problem

Comment: Changed my answer.